# Error in current voltage relation?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, temperature, electric-current, semiconductor-physics

The current voltage relation of diode is given by
I=(e^(1000V/t)-1)mA,where the applied voltage V
is in volts and the temprature T is in degree Kelvin.
If I made an error measuring +-0.01 V while measuring 
current of 5mA at 300k,what will be the error
in the value of current in mA?

This problem was asked last year in IIT-Jee .I was unable to figure it out..
please tell me about this..

Answer (score 1):

Find the value of voltage $V$ from the given relations,$$I=e^{\Large \frac{1000 \, \mathrm{V}}{T}}-1
\qquad \text{and} \qquad
V=\frac{T}{1000}\ln\left(I+1\right)
\,,$$
then take the derivative of $V$ with respect to $I$, keeping $T$ constant as follows:
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}V}{\mathrm{d}I}=\frac{T}{1000}\cdot \frac{1}{I+1}
\qquad \text{and} \qquad
\mathrm{d}I=\frac{1000 \left(I+1\right) \,\mathrm{d}V}{T}
\,.$$
Find the change in current $dI$ for given change in voltage $\mathrm{d}V=2\times 0.1\,\mathrm{V}$, at given current $I=5\,\mathrm{mA}$
 & temperature $T=300\,\mathrm{K}.$